# how to select column name from a inner query

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am trying to do something like 
`select * from  table_name`

I will get the table_name from below query:

```
select distinct table_name table_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'test_table'
```

Is there any  other way to do it other than execute Immediate

Comment: This makes no sense. You are trying to fetch the same value that you pass in as a constant?

Comment: No its not possible to have without using dynamic sql to suffice such requirement,

Comment: Thanks Xing for the confirmation

Comment: You can sometimes do this kind of thing (dynamic SQL within SQL) using XML, although the result will be XML rather than a relational tabular result set.